# JQuery Naming Dynamic Elements and children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I've been trying all night to get a dynamically created set of table to change their class.

Normally JQuery will let you do this:

```
$('table tbody tr').click(function () {
    // remove clickedRow class from all same level rows?
    $(this).addClass('clickedRow');
});
```

I want to apply something similar but to a specific but dynamically created id.  I've tried

```
$(idname 'tbody tr')
```

and

```
$('idname tbody tr')
```

but haven't been able to find a work around.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put `#` before IDs. And you have to use proper Javascript string concatenation syntax.

```
$("#" + idname + " tbody tr")
```

However, if you want to bind a handler to elements that will be created dynamically, it's usually better to use delegation. See

[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You need the ID selector http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

```
$('#idname tbody tr')
```

or

```
$('#' + idname + ' tbody tr')
```